# How can I apply negative margin to an inline block?

Tags: html, css

https://jsfiddle.net/yLrnp1x2/ In this fiddle I have a span element which I want to give a negative top-margin. I can not seem to succeed in any other way than defining `display:block;` for the span, which the demo will illustrate  is obviously useless.

The elements chosen to populate the menu div, including the span, haven't been given any special thought and can be changed to anything that will achieve the same result. How can I achieve this?

```css
.outer {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 10px;
}

.label {
  background-color: azure;
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
}

.menu {
  text-align: right;
  background-color: burlywood;
  /* margin: 3px; */
  /* padding-top: -5px; */
}

.menu a {
  background-color: blueviolet;
  cursor: pointer;
  /* padding-top: 10px; */
}

.menu span {
  background-color: green;
  /* display: inline-block; */
  margin-top: -5px;
}
```

```html
<div class='outer'>
  <div class='label'>
    Some model
  </div>
  <div class='menu'>
    <a>Edit</a>
    <span>&nbsp;|&nbsp;</span>
    <a>Delete</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try `position: relative; top: -5px`

Comment: @SalmanA That seems to work and no immediate side effects. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to fix the alignment of the standard bar `|` character, which is displayed a little lower in HTML. You can use the Drawing Vertical Bar instead. To do so, you can either use its entity `&boxv;` or its code `&#9474;`. The code is guaranteed to work, but the entity may not be supported in all browsers.

```css
.outer {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 10px;
}

.label {
  background-color: azure;
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
}

.menu {
  text-align: right;
  background-color: burlywood;
}

.menu a {
  background-color: blueviolet;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu span {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class='outer'>
  <div class='label'>
    Some model
  </div>
  <div class='menu'>
    <a>Edit</a>
    <span>&nbsp;&#9474;&nbsp;</span> <!-- or <span>&nbsp;&boxv;&nbsp;</span> -->
    <a>Delete</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, it is more commonly done using borders. Something like this:

```css
.outer {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 10px;
}

.label {
  background-color: azure;
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
}

.menu {
  text-align: right;
  background-color: burlywood;
}

.menu a {
  background-color: blueviolet;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-right: 3px;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
}

.menu a:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<div class='outer'>
  <div class='label'>
    Some model
  </div>
  <div class='menu'>
    <a>Edit</a>
    <a>Delete</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
 set `position: absolute;` for your span element. Also you can use pseudo class `:before` to put your divider before last `a` element. It's a better semantic way of coding

```css
.outer {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 10px;
}

.label {
  background-color: azure;
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
}

.menu {
  text-align: right;
  background-color: burlywood;
  /* margin: 3px; */
  /* padding-top: -5px; */
}

.menu a {
  background-color: blueviolet;
  cursor: pointer;
  /* padding-top: 10px; */
}

.menu a:last-child {
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.menu span {
  background-color: green;
  margin-top: -2px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Title</title>

  <style>

  </style>

</head>
<body>
 
<div class='outer'>
  <div class='label'>
    Some model
  </div>
  <div class='menu'>
    <a>Edit</a>
    <span>&nbsp;|&nbsp;</span>
    <a>Delete</a>
  </div>
</div>

<script>


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the position absolute helped in something, thanks